# retrieve data using BQL in Acumatica

Tags: c#, customization, acumatica

I already create extension for APReleaseCheckProcess. I need to send RefNbr of document where DocType = 'REF' (send RefNbr of Vendor Refund) to another database.
I used this code below.

```
public static class APReleaseCheckProcess
  {
      public static void APPaymentRowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e)
      {
          string serverJade, dbJade, userJade, passJade;

          serverJade = "BS-DEV64\\SQL2014"; //--- Server Jade : 192.168.10.13
          dbJade = "SGL"; //--- DB Jade Live : SGL || DB Jade test : SGL_TEST
          userJade = "sa"; //--- User ID : sa
          passJade = "Admin1"; //--- Password : sa_091073

          if (e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed && e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Update)
          {
              var doc = e.Row as APPayment;
              #region Doc Type = Vendor Refund
              if (doc != null && doc.Released == true && doc.DocType == "REF")
              {
                  foreach (APAdjust oldadj in PXSelect<APAdjust,
                      Where<
                          APAdjust.adjgDocType, Equal<Required<APPayment.docType>>,
                              And<APAdjust.adjgRefNbr, Equal<Required<APPayment.refNbr>>,
                              And<APAdjust.adjNbr, Less<Required<APPayment.lineCntr>>>>>>
                      .Select(sender.Graph, doc.DocType, doc.RefNbr, doc.LineCntr))
                  {
                      string refNbr = oldadj.AdjdRefNbr;
                      string docType = oldadj.AdjdDocType;

                      // I need to retrieve InvoiceNbr from this query below using BQL statement:
                      string InvNbr = "select InvoiceNbr from APInvoice where CompanyID = 2 and RefNbr = refnbr";

                      // query to send to another database
                      using (SqlConnection conJade = new SqlConnection("server = " + serverJade + "; database = " + dbJade + "; user = " + userJade + "; password = " + passJade + ""))
                                  {
                                      string qRefund = "update b set b.cano = "+doc.RefNbr+"" +
                                                       "from evmaster as b " +
                                                            "inner join evmaster as a on a.svno = b.vchno " +
                                                       "where a.vchno = "+InvNbr+"";
                                      conJade.Open();
                                      using (SqlCommand comJade = new SqlCommand(qRefund, conJade))
                                      {
                                          SqlDataReader sdr = comJade.ExecuteReader();
                                          sdr.Close();
                                      }
                                  }
                  }
              }
              #endregion
          }
      }
  }
```

How to write the code to generate query above using BQL in Acumatica Customize project.

Comment: Have you checked the API Reference and training materials at Acumatica University?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll check it. Actually the answer below has been work, and I will use it. But I think if I have another case regarding of BQL I will check the training materials surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to run the query for the company of the logged in user, without error checking that would be:

```
((APInvoice)PXSelect<APInvoice, Where<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Required<APInvoice.refNbr>>>>.Select(sender.Graph, refNbr)).InvoiceNbr
```

If you need to run the query for a company other than the company of the logged in user, the recommended way is to put the data in a table without a CompanyID field.

The isolation of companies is strongly enforced by BQL, and you won't be able to retrieve data from another company unless you're logged into this company. The ORM also takes care of returning you the data from other company IDs if this data is split/shared with another company. For tables that don't contain a CompanyID field, the system returns all the data contained in this table.

Comment: I need to run the query for the curent company, of course it will be same with the logged in user. I have tried your BQL and it works. Thank's for your answer :)